# Using single digit user input as end of range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to take a single digit user input and use that to copy a number of rows i.e userinput = n -> rows(1:n). I have succeeded in copying the range if the user inputs the range:

```
Set rng = Application.InputBox("mytext", Type:=8)
```

but I need to do this by only supplying a single digit as described as my co-workers cant write '1:' prior to the wished number of rows. My entire code is supplied below.

Thank you in advance

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("mytext", Type:=8)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = rng.EntireRow
    rng.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Rows("9").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A1").Rows("9").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to get a single digit from the user, the other answer by @udearboy will do what you intend to, but if I understood correctly and you want the end user to give you the last row to be copied then the following will achieve that for you:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
'declare and set the worksheets you are working with
    ws2.Activate
    n = Application.InputBox("Enter the number for the last row to copy:", Type:=1)
    'get input from user
    If IsNumeric(n) Then 'check if input is numeric
        ws2.Range("1:" & n).EntireRow.Copy 'copy range
        ws1.Range("A1").Rows("9").Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert the values
        ws1.Range("A1").Rows("9").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats 'copy formats
        ws1.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

I've made a slight amendment to the code to check that the value entered by the user is a whole number and greater than 0, so you should get any errors because of incorrectly entered values, I would probably also check that the value entered is within the Range of data on the worksheet, but I haven't added that below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
'declare and set the worksheets you are working with
    ws2.Activate
    n = Application.InputBox("Enter the number for the last row to copy:", "Please enter a Number", Type:=1)
    'get input from user
    If (IsNumeric(n)) And (CDbl(n) - CInt(n) = 0) And (n > 0) Then
    'check if input is numeric and a whole number and greater than 0
            ws2.Range("1:" & n).EntireRow.Copy 'copy range
            ws1.Range("A1").Rows("9").Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert the values
            ws1.Range("A1").Rows("9").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats 'copy formats
            ws1.Activate
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a whole number greater than 0", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Wajn I've updated the code to check the value entered is a valid whole number greater than 0, hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to go about validating the entry of a input box. The below code will only allow for the entry to be numeric and has to be in range 1 - 9. Anything else will display a `MsgBox` and `Exit Sub`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim n As Integer

n = Application.InputBox("Enter # 1 - 9", Type:=1)

If n > 9 Then
    MsgBox "Entry Larger than 9. Please try again"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf n < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Entry less than 1. Please try again"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Your code goes here once all validatoins are complete

End Sub
```